# Can I revert a USB flash drive to it's previous state?

Tags: usb, iso, macosx, disk-image

I downloaded a USB disk image (.iso file) of 12.04 Precise and followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles) to create a Mac OSX bootable disk (.dmg file).  The flash drive is enormous (~64 GB), and contained many other things, which I fear have been erased.  In the Mac file browser ("Finder"), the USB drive doesn't even show up, as if there is no filesystem mounted.

**Can somebody confirm that this process wipes the drive clean before creating the disk image?**  Is the previous filesystem permanently gone?

Comment: Paragraph 4 from your link:
    Warning: This will destroy all data on the destination device. Please backup all data to other media before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to recover the data with Testdisk.  Now keep in mind that its not guaranteed to recover anything, but give it a try.

> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily
>   designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks
>   bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software,
>   certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting
>   a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really
>   easy.

For more information on Testdisk, and to download the software, visit their [website](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

<sup>Source:TestDisk</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I use *Data Rescue* on the Mac, but yes, your drive is pretty trashed.  Recovery is unlikely because you overwrote it.